# VLC detecting stream type on command line

Tags: command-line, vlc

Is there a way to dump information about the stream from vlc on command line?

I mean codec used by the stream, bitrate, and all that good stuff without even playing the stream.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find out that, too.

The answer is no.  Command line of vlc doesn't support that as I know.

Comment: Looks like the tool to use is mplayer. The command: mplayer -novideo -ao null -frames 0 -identify -prefer-ipv4 URL